# Java defining custom exceptions inside of class, is this bad?

Tags: java, exception

I have a class that has a method.  The method may fail and I want to throw an exception.  Is it bad to define the exception class within the namespace of the class whose function is throwing the exception?  I haven't seen a lot of examples of this, but it seems like the "right" (i.e. OO) way to do it?  Is there a reason I should avoid this pattern and define each custom exception in its own file?

```
public class Foo
{
    void bar() {
        // do something and throw BarException if something bad happens
    }

    public static class BarException extends Exception {
        // rest of class definition
    }
}
```

Comment: I personally can't think of any reason it would be wrong to do this.

Comment: Though syntactically it is not wrong, When it is static, I feel  it is not really OO and prefer move it to separate class.

Comment: The only bad thing is the `Bar` method, it's name should start with a small `b` :)

Comment: It's not any more or less OOP than a separate class-there's no generalized answer. I'd find catching a class-qualified exception stylistically awkward, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the advice.  I come from a C++ background, so the advantage of the outer class namespace seems more OO like to me?  I.e. in the scope of the class, I can just type BarException and it is resolved to the correct BarException.  Purely a namespace advantage IMHO, but I'm not as familiar with Java standard conventions.

Comment: @JoshPetitt It should be unusual to have app-specific exceptions colliding with existing exceptions. If they have the same name and semantics then the value of the app- specific exception is questionable, and potentially confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it depends on the possible scope of the `Exception` you're creating.  If it will only have to do with `Foo`, and only `Foo`, forever, then creating it as a nested class would be good.

Just make sure it makes sense for something calling `Bar` to say:

```
catch (Foo.BarException e)
```

instead of

```
catch (BarException e)
```

Else, create it as its own standalone class.

As for the namespace, a Java class *could* be used for namespacing classes, but generally in Java packages are used for namespacing your classes.  I would only use a nested class if there is a very high coupling between the main class and the other class.

Comment: thanks.  I'll accept this answer since it covers the dilemma I was facing (i.e. class namespace versus package namespace).  I see now that was the crux of my question.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use this pattern.

- You add more line to class.
- This class has more than one concern
- and you will get problems, if you want to use the same Exception in another class.

Why do you want to do this? Just, because you don't want to create a new file? ;)

In Java you should only ad one public class in one file. Sometimes I add public interfaces into classes, most for event handling.

```
class MyEvent {
    public void registerHandler(MyEvent.Handler h){
        //
    }
    public interface Handler(){
        handle();
    }

}
```

In this case I am absolute sure, there wont be any other class using this Interface.

Comment: see my comment above about namespacing.  That was the only reason I was using the pattern.  I prefer Foo.BarException to FooBarException, since the class is a namespace as well?

Comment: I don't want to use the exception for another class.  It is the specific exception that is thrown if Foo.bar() fails.  Does this change your opinion?  BTW, thanks for the words of wisdom.

Comment: No, I still won't do it. You wrote 'namespace', therefore I think you are from the .NET corner. The packages are used for separating namespaces.